# Перенос базы в другую без потери данных

Tags: python, django

Для регистрации и авторизации я использовал стандартную модель `User`, где имеются поля `email`, `password`. Но мне нужно теперь добавить возможность регистрировать пользователей по номеру телефона. То есть добавить поле `phone`.

Возможно ли это реализовать без потери данных? И каким образом это реализовать? Гуглил, так и не нашел интересующую мне тему или не правильно сформулировал свой вопрос. Был бы признателен за ресурсы

Comment: неправильно сформулировали вопрос, добавьте в таблицу поле телефона, включите его в вашу модель и заполняйте как уже существующие поля

Comment: Вы планируете использовать номер телефона вместо почты для авторизации/регистрации или хотите просто добавить это поле, как дополнительное?

Comment: Да, хочу добавить новое поле phone.

Answer (score 0):

К моделям:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    phone = models.TextField(max_length=24, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Обратиться к телефону можно будет через: `user.profile.phone`, где `user` - объект пользователя. Таким же образом, к пользователю, имея профиль: `profile.user`.

**Не забудьте создать и выполнить миграции.**

Скорее всего у Вас не будет профилей у уже созданных пользователей. Для этого запустите shell: `python manage.py shell` и выполните следующие действия:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from название_приложения.models import Profile # замените название_приложения на ваше
for user in User.objects.all(): # после ввода этой строки добавьте табуляцию
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user) # нажмите дважды Enter
```